# equals only when put into variables

Tags: java, equals

I have two values to be compared. They appear to be not equal when compared directly using the `==` operator, but equal after they are put into local variables. Could anyone tell me why?

The code is as follows:

```
(MgrBean.getByName(name1).getId() == MgrBean.getByName(name2).getId()),
//This one is false,

int a = MgrBean.getByName(name1).getId();
int b = MgrBean.getByName(name2).getId();
(a == b); //This one is true.
```

Comment: What is getId() returning..

Comment: `MgrBean.getByName(name1).getId()` might be returning Integer or int type?

Comment: @Devavrata Since in the code, the result of `getId()` is assigned to an `int` local variable, it is safe to assume that the result is probably a primitive type.

Comment: it will be good if you can show the code of `getId()` and the corresponding class

Comment: Can you share the code of `MgrBean`, so you can see `getByName` method ?

Answer (score -1):

I believe your `getId()` is returning an `Integer` instead of `int`.

`Integer` is the wrapper class for `int` primitive type.  If you compare object reference using `==`, you are comparing if they are referring to same object, instead of comparing the value inside.  Hence if you are comparing two `Integer` objects reference, you are not comparing its integer value, you are simply checking if that two reference is pointing to same `Integer` object.

However, if you use a primitive type to store that value (e.g. `int a = ....getId()`), there is auto-unboxing happening, and that wrapper object is converted to primitive type value, and comparing primitive type values using `==` is comparing the value, which do the work you expect.

Suggested further reading for you:

1. Primitive Type vs Reference Type in Java
2. Auto-boxing and unboxing in Java

Comment: @Adrain Shum, your answer is correct though, but not applicable to this if I am correct.

Comment: @Reddy What is the difference between your answers?

Comment: @Adrain Shum, no offence. You didn't mention about Integer Pool. For sure, newbie will not understand if he goes with that example and again in dilemma

Comment: @Reddy I do skip mentioning the pool intentionally because: 1. I believe it is more important to understand the meaning of object reference comparison, and XXX Pool is nothing difficult to understand with the basic knowledge  2. Integer Pool, afaik, is not in JLS.  That means it is possible that a JVM is not implementing that.  Mentioning that to OP is simply blurring the focus.

Comment: @Reddy and most important is, this problem has nothing to do with Integer pool.

Comment: The pool itself isn't. But the [JLS does say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) `If the value p being boxed is an integer literal of type int between -128 and 127 inclusive (§3.10.1), or the boolean literal true or false (§3.10.3), or a character literal between '\u0000' and '\u007f' inclusive (§3.10.4), then let a and b be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that a == b.` That has to be satisfied regardless of the implementation.

Comment: @AdrianShum, it's. that's where people get misguided :)

Comment: @Reddy It is not in fact.  The Integer pool is affecting `==` comparison of Integer object comes from auto-boxing.  However, in OP's case, first comparison is unequal, which can only happen for unpooled `Integer` instances.  Second comparison is equals but that's comparing `int`, which is simply comparison of primitive type (which comes from auto-unboxing of `Integer`), which have nothing to do with Integer Pool.

Answer (score -1):

`The most misconception about Integer type happens everywhere including other answers here`

Suppose you have two integers defined as follows:

```
Integer i1 = 128
Integer i2 = 128
```

`If you then execute the test (i1 == i2), the returned result is false. The reason is that the JVM maintains a pool of Integer values (similar to the one it maintains for Strings). But the pool contains only integers from -128 to 127. Creating any Integer in that range results in Java assigning those Integers from the pool, so the equivalency test works. However, for values greater than 127 and less than -128), the pool does not come into play, so the two assignments create different objects, which then fail the equivalency test and return false.`

In contast, consider the following assignments:

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(1); // Any number in the Integer pool range
Integer i2 = new Integer(1); // Any number in the Integer pool range
```

Because these assignments are made using the 'new' keyword, they are new instances created, and not picked up from the pool. Hence, testing (i1== i2) on the preceding assignments returns false.

Here's some code that illustrates the Integer pool:

```
public class IntegerPoolTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Integer i1 = 100;
        Integer i2 = 100;
        // Comparison of integers from the pool - returns true.
        compareInts(i1, i2); 

        Integer i3 = 130;
        Integer i4 = 130;
        // Same comparison, but from outside the pool 
        // (not in the range -128 to 127)
        // resulting in false.
        compareInts(i3, i4); 

        Integer i5 = new Integer(100);
        Integer i6 = new Integer(100);
        // Comparison of Integers created using the 'new' keyword 
        // results in new instances and '==' comparison leads to false.
        compareInts(i5, i6); 

    }

    private static void compareInts(Integer i1, Integer i2){
        System.out.println("Comparing Integers " + 
           i1 + "," + i2 + " results in: " + (i1 == i2) );
    }
}
```

Comment: No offend ( :P ) but you have spent your whole answer describing the Integer pool (for literals etc), but that has nothing to do with with OP's problem:  First, obviously the two Integer object in OP's problem is not pooled, and second, the "equals" in the second part of his question has nothing to do with pooling either.